# Why is my new large diameter ceiling fan so slow on high speed?

Tags: ceiling-fan

This is the 2nd fan that I purchased and it moves slow for such a large fan. Do smaller fans run faster? My 1st fan was a Harbor Breeze Saratoga 60" that had an air flow of 7344 CFMs on high speed. This one is a Altura 68". I returned it thinking something was wrong with the interior of the fan.

Next, I connected Hampton Bay Altura 68" that has an air flow of 8,435 CFM, and to see it run the same speed as my previous fan is dumbfounding. What is wrong with the speed? It's connected directly to the power wires. I have a dimmer switch in the kitchen but didn't connect the wires to it. Please help!

Comment: I don't think you meant "direct current". You maybe meant "directly to the breaker".

Answer (score 6):

Your new fan is larger, which means it should be able to move more air at the same speed. As you say, it moves more air (8435 CFM, up from 7344). Who cares how fast the blades turn? If anything it's probably quieter to have a slow, large fan vs a small fan that has to spin a lot faster to move the same amount of air.

Answer (score 2):

CFM (Cubic Feet per Minute) is a measure of the volume of air being moved. A larger fan can move more air while rotating at the same speed as a smaller fan. So if you're simply looking at the fan size and CFM, you can expect that at the same CFM a larger fan will spin slower.

Answer (score 2):

I used to own this fan in a previous house, installed in a large vaulted family room.

The blades do move slow when compared to smaller fans.  When I mean slow, it felt like it was on low when it was on high.  But I will say, this fan worked well and we rarely needed to turn that fan on high.  It was in a 400sqf room and no mater where we were, we could feel the air movement with the fan on medium.  With those large blades, being directly under it also didn't feel like being in a tornado that smaller fans are like.